# How to style ProgressBar like in Google Fit?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Can anyone help me to make such ProgressBar as in Google Fit application? Like on image below:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can review this library [Progressbar with number](https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar) and can customize background of progress bar from its property. Use [nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) image to make it awesome.